# A better way to write an if statement in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

Having several scripts which follow the below pattern, and I'm curious if you folks have suggestions on reducing the number of lines or if you're doing this more streamlined?

What I don't like necessarily is that I'm using too many $? checks, and end up with nested if loops - not sure if that is a bad thing though.

Code I'm looking to optimize but still keep the functionality is like this:

```
wget -V > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    apt install wget
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        "failed to install wget" 
    fi
fi
```

Comment: What is your Linux flavor ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 7 lines of code, nor with $? using multiple times, there is no quota for that. :) If you have the same pattern more than twice in your file, you can write a function, which expects the name ("wget") and call that function several times. If you need that functionality again and again, you can put the function into your .bashrc-file, or into a script, which you place in your path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oneliner using `hash`:

```
hash wget 2>/dev/null || echo 'wget is not installed'
```

If you need to install, you can do

```
hash wget 2>/dev/null || apt install -y wget || echo 'failed to install wget'
```

again, oneliner.

More specifically, `hash` is a reliable way in shell to check if a binary exists in `$PATH`. you can check info about `hash` as following:

```
$ help hash
hash: hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
    Remember or display program locations.

    Determine and remember the full pathname of each command NAME.  If
    no arguments are given, information about remembered commands is displayed.

    Options: ...

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless NAME is not found or an invalid option is given.
```

Comment: learning something new everyday, didn't know about #hash :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general, you don't need to check `$?` explicitly unless you are looking for a particular non-zero exit code. You can rewrite your code as:

```
if ! wget -V &> /dev/null; then
  if ! apt install wget; then
     echo "failed to install wget" 
  fi
fi
```

Or, even more concisely:

```
wget -V &> /dev/null || apt install wget || echo "failed to install wget"
```

Comment: thanks codeforester! the first suggestion is still doing 2 if's, but the one liner sounds interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I try to get the big picture behind, and I think you try to re-invent the wheel.

The said wheel is `command-not-found` on [debian](/questions/tagged/debian) and derivatives.

It makes proposition when a command failed automatically.

You just have to do :

```
 apt-get install command-not-found
 update-command-not-found
 wget -V # or any missing command
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is an installer script, don't check, just install. Any packages that are already installed will be skipped anyways:

```
apt install wget jq texlive-latex-base || exit 1
```

If this is a normal script, *don't install missing dependencies*, especially not without the user's consent. This is not the script's job, and it's much more intrusive than helpful.

If you still want to do it, just put it in a function. Here's an example:

```
require() {
  # Assume $1 is command and $3 is package (or same as command)
  set -- "$1" from "${3:-$1}"
  if ! { type "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 || apt install "$3"; }
  then
    echo "$1 was missing, but installation of $3 failed" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
}

require wget
require jq
require latex from texlive-latex-base
```